# Introduced infinite loop, using jquery and MVC, can't find what is causing it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, http-post

I seem to have introduced an infinite loop somehow.
I am using MVC2 and attempting to use jQuery `post` or `ajax` - but it seems to be happening for either.

The idea is the users enters ids into a textfield, then I search db for the id's and then display the objects in a grid.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function bulk() {
        var data = $("#textfield").val();
        $.post("Search", { searchString: data });
    }
    </script>
```

Which posts to controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
{
...
return View(viewModel);
}
```

Problem is, (whether using `ajax` or `post`) I get stackoverflow after entering ids into the textbox and hitting the search button. It seems likely cause by infinite loop but I can't work out why it is happening. What happens is after this line:
`$.post("Search", { searchString: data });`

I hit the action method: `public ActionResult Search(string searchString)` then everything goes as normal, search the db, add to view model, then after `return View(viewModel);` I just go straight back to `public ActionResult Search(string searchString)` over and over again.

I'm at a complete loss to why this is happening. Any ideas what might be happening?

**edit**: `bulk` is called through a button click `<input type="submit" onclick="bulk()" value="Search" />`

@Daniel, I get `StackOverflowException` was unhandled

An unhandled exception of type `'System.StackOverflowException'` occured in mscorlib.dll
If I click View detail - Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

It occurs in the Entity Framework code

```
public Entities() : base("name=Entities", "Entities")
{
this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
OnContextCreated();
}
```

Comment: Seems like the bulk() function is being called in an infinite loop. Where/how is the bulk() function called?

Comment: If you use Fiddler, do you see a huge number of requests following a single click (even so, that shouldn't cause a stack overflow!)? If you unittest (or otherwise call) that Search method, do you still get the stack overflow?

Answer (score 1):

In your view, are you calling `@Html.Action()` helper by any chance? (as opposed to `@Html.ActionLink()`)

You should also be able to just press F5 to debug the app, let it blow up, and inspect the Call Stack to find the offending code that's causing the infinite look.

Comment: No `Html.Action()`  or `Html.ActionLink()`, I just manually set the url like "Search" (going to localhost:4034/Contoller/Search)

Comment: I see you are using lazy loading on EF. Depending on what you're doing in your view, that could be another potential cause. Just to test it out, if you are returning an IQueryable<>, you can try adding appending a `.ToList()` to let your controller retrieve the data, instead of your view.